# How to test key down event on material ui MenuList component using react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have the following MenuList component on which I want to test key down event.

**Component**:

```
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import MenuList from '@material-ui/core/MenuList';
import * as React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MenuList autoFocusItem={true}>
        <MenuItem>option 1</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>option 2</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>option 3</MenuItem>
      </MenuList>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Test**:

```
import {
    fireEvent,
    render,
} from 'test-utils';
import React from 'react';
import TestMenuList from './TestMenuList';

test('that on key down press, the focus on menu list item moves down', async () => {
    // Render component
    const { getAllByRole, getByRole } = render(<TestMenuList />, {});

    let MenuItem1 = getAllByRole('menuitem')[0];
    expect(MenuItem1.classList.contains('Mui-focusVisible')).toBe(true); // assert 1

    const Menu = getByRole('menu');
    fireEvent.keyDown(Menu, { Key: 'ArrowDown', code: 40 });

    MenuItem1 = getAllByRole('menuitem')[0];
    const MenuItem2 = getAllByRole('menuitem')[1];
    expect(MenuItem1.classList.contains('Mui-focusVisible')).toBe(false); // assert 2
    expect(MenuItem2.classList.contains('Mui-focusVisible')).toBe(true); // assert 3
});
```

To make sure that a menu item is in focus, I'm checking if the menu item has class `Mui-focusVisible`. Since I set `autoFocusItem={true}` in `MenuList`, the first menu item should automatically have `Mui-focusVisible` class added to it. That is assertion statement 1 which is passing.

```
    let MenuItem1 = getAllByRole('menuitem')[0];
    expect(MenuItem1.classList.contains('Mui-focusVisible')).toBe(true); // assert 1
```

Then I fired a key down event on the menu

```
    const Menu = getByRole('menu');
    fireEvent.keyDown(Menu, { Key: 'ArrowDown', code: 40 });
```

And checked if the `Mui-focusVisible` class has been removed from first menu item and added to 2nd menu item. Now, the test is failing at assertion statements 2 and 3.

```
    MenuItem1 = getAllByRole('menuitem')[0];
    const MenuItem2 = getAllByRole('menuitem')[1];
    expect(MenuItem1.classList.contains('Mui-focusVisible')).toBe(false); // assert 2
    expect(MenuItem2.classList.contains('Mui-focusVisible')).toBe(true); // assert 3
```

I logged `classList` for `MenuItem1` and `MenuItem2` to see if `Mui-focusVisible` is removed from first menu item and added to 2nd menu item after the key down event. But the `Mui-focusVisible` class is still in first menu item and not in the 2nd one.

I tried adding `await wait()`.

```
fireEvent.keyDown(Menu, { Key: 'ArrowDown', code: 40 });
await wait();
```

wrapping the fireevent with `act(() => {})`,

```
act(() => fireEvent.keyDown(Menu, { Key: 'ArrowDown', code: 40 }));
await wait()
```

firing key down event on first menu list item instead of the menu itself.

```
act(() => fireEvent.keyDown(MenuItem1, { Key: 'ArrowDown', code: 40 }));
await wait()
```

None of them worked. I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-cloud-2fus7) for this component and here, it seems to work perfectly in the UI. But the test is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking over the integration tests for `MenuList`: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.4/packages/material-ui/test/integration/MenuList.test.js.

The keyboard navigation is tested very thoroughly. You'll find though, that it primarily checks for the element having focus rather than checking for `Mui-focusVisible`. The focus-visible logic (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.4/packages/material-ui/src/utils/focusVisible.js) depends on tracking mouse and keyboard events at the document level and it is not easy to trigger this reliably in test frameworks (though you can look at the tests for the focus-visible logic here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.4/packages/material-ui/src/utils/focusVisible.test.js). I would recommend driving your tests off of focus and rely on Material-UI to manage and test applying the `Mui-focusVisible` class.